# Debian 9 RTL8188CE WiFi driver problem

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, drivers

I just installed Debian 9 on my Toshiba Satellite L755D-S5106. I followed the instructions [here](https://wiki.debian.org/rtl819x) to install the driver for my WiFi Adapter, but it seems like this doesn't work. I can't find a way to make it work.

Here's the output of `lspci`:

```
$ lspci -nn | grep Network
02:00.0 Network Controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8176] (rev 01)
```

My repositories:

```
deb  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free

deb  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

And the output of `rfkill list all`:

```
$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

The output of `lsmod` is:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
nls_ascii              16384  1
nls_cp437              20480  1
vfat                   20480  1
fat                    69632  1 vfat
uas                    24576  0
usb_storage            73728  2 uas
fuse                   98304  3
uvcvideo               90112  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
videodev              176128  3 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
media                  40960  2 uvcvideo,videodev
arc4                   16384  2
rtl8192ce              61440  0
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8192ce
rtl8192c_common        53248  1 rtl8192ce
rtlwifi                98304  3 rtl_pci,rtl8192ce,rtl8192c_common
kvm_amd              2179072  0
kvm                   589824  1 kvm_amd
snd_hda_codec_conexant    24576  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    69632  1 snd_hda_codec_conexant
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
snd_hda_intel          36864  8
joydev                 20480  0
evdev                  24576  19
amdkfd                139264  1
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
mac80211              671744  3 rtl_pci,rtl8192ce,rtlwifi
cfg80211              589824  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
toshiba_acpi           45056  0
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic
serio_raw              16384  0
pcspkr                 16384  0
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic
radeon               1486848  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 toshiba_acpi
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               110592  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
industrialio           69632  1 toshiba_acpi
k10temp                16384  0
toshiba_bluetooth      16384  0
rfkill                 24576  5 toshiba_bluetooth,toshiba_acpi,cfg80211
sg                     32768  0
snd_timer              32768  1 snd_pcm
snd                    86016  24 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_pcm
ttm                    98304  1 radeon
wmi                    16384  1 toshiba_acpi
sp5100_tco             16384  0
shpchp                 36864  0
video                  40960  1 toshiba_acpi
ac                     16384  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
drm_kms_helper        155648  1 radeon
drm                   360448  3 radeon,ttm,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 radeon
button                 16384  0
battery                20480  0
acpi_cpufreq           20480  0
parport_pc             28672  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
ip_tables              24576  0
x_tables               36864  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
ext4                  585728  2
crc16                  16384  1 ext4
jbd2                  106496  1 ext4
crc32c_generic         16384  4
fscrypto               28672  1 ext4
ecb                    16384  0
glue_helper            16384  0
lrw                    16384  0
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
ablk_helper            16384  0
cryptd                 24576  1 ablk_helper
aes_x86_64             20480  0
mbcache                16384  3 ext4
sr_mod                 24576  0
cdrom                  61440  1 sr_mod
sd_mod                 45056  6
ohci_pci               16384  0
psmouse               135168  0
ahci                   36864  3
libahci                32768  1 ahci
ohci_hcd               53248  1 ohci_pci
ehci_pci               16384  0
ehci_hcd               81920  1 ehci_pci
i2c_piix4              24576  0
libata                249856  2 ahci,libahci
usbcore               249856  7 uvcvideo,usb_storage,ehci_hcd,ohci_pci,uas,ohci_hcd,ehci_pci
scsi_mod              225280  6 sd_mod,usb_storage,libata,uas,sr_mod,sg
usb_common             16384  1 usbcore
atl1c                  49152  0
thermal                20480  0
```

Comment: 1)Have you rebooted? 2) "Hard blocked" cannot be changed by software, look for a wifi switch on your keyboard or edges of the laptop; the device can also be hard blocked if disabled in the bios.

Comment: @arochester hi, thanks for yoür answer. Yes, I have tried rebooting, but nothing happens. There's no switch, I've tried with Fn + F8 but it seems to do nothing. I also checked the bios but it was OK, just to be sure I reestablished factory defaults but it did nothing.

Comment: @GAD3R Hi! Thanks for the answer. I did what you said bit the hard block stayed. Ten I ran the `ip link set wlp2s0 up` but got this: `RTNETLICK answers: Operation not possible due to RF-kill`.

Comment: @GAD3R I've editted the post with the `lsmod` output. Seems like the modules are loaded, Also, I can access  the networks and I can see the wireless option, but it's not active and it can't be activated. The airplane mode is turned on and can't be deactivated

Comment: Do you have a dual-boot on that machine? If so, does the Wifi work with the other OS?

Comment: On the Internet, you can see that others are having the exact same problem with the `rtl8192ce` module, and that the problem disappeared with the `rtl8188ce` module [as suggested below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/386739/203203) by Patrice Remy.

Comment: @xhienne Hi! Thanks for answering. Yes, it's a dual boot machine. I have Windows 10 and Debian 9 installed, and yes, WiFi works with Windows. I'll try Patrice Remy's answer and let you all know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try loading the module with:

sudo modprobe rtl8192ce

(the rtl8188ce & rtl8192ce use the same module)

or if that doesn't work, try installing that driver:

https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver

I'm using it with a rtl8188ce mini pci card  (Lenovo h520s PC).
It's slow compared to a bcm4318.

Comment: You can see from the original post that rtl8192ce module is already loaded. Your answer is not clear, do you suggest that the OP unloads the module provided by his distribution and use the one from that github repository instead?

Comment: This worked! Thanks Patrice and @xhienne! I had been 2 weeks without WiFi, I was starting to loose hope!